# Android HTTP request with specific port

Tags: android, http, shoutcast, icecast

I am trying to get the song title from a Shoutcast server. So, my idea was to do a little regexp on 7.html page of Shoutcast server, BUT I can't get simple HttpGet request to receive 7.html page. What am I doing wrong?

If I remove port number from link, HttpGet will run without any problems, but I won't get my results.

```
private class GetTrackInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... Urls) {

        String url = urls[0];
        if(!url.contains("http://")) url = "http://" + url;
        url = url + "/7.html";
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpGet http = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(http);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
        String res = out.toString();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("GetTrack", "Track result: " + result);
        String[] results = result.split(",");
        String track = results[results.length-1];
        fplayer.setStreamInfoTxt(track);
    }

}
```

As an error, I get:

> 01-29 23:28:10.461: W/System.err(962): org.Apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
>   01-29 23:28:10.471: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.Java:557)
>   01-29 23:28:10.471: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.Java:487)
>   01-29 23:28:10.471: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.Java:465)
>   01-29 23:28:10.471: W/System.err(962):    at com.imsgroups.exyuradio.services.PlayerService$GetTrackInfo.doInBackground(PlayerService.Java:257)
>   01-29 23:28:10.471: W/System.err(962):    at com.imsgroups.exyuradio.services.PlayerService$GetTrackInfo.doInBackground(PlayerService.Java:1)
>   01-29 23:28:10.481: W/System.err(962):    at Android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.Java:185)
>   01-29 23:28:10.481: W/System.err(962):    at Java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.Java:305)
>   01-29 23:28:10.491: W/System.err(962):    at Java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.Java:137)
>   01-29 23:28:10.491: W/System.err(962):    at Java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.Java:1068)
>   01-29 23:28:10.491: W/System.err(962):    at Java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.Java:561)
>   01-29 23:28:10.491: W/System.err(962):    at Java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.Java:1096)
>   01-29 23:28:10.491: W/System.err(962): Caused by: org.Apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
>   01-29 23:28:10.511: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.Java:93)
>   01-29 23:28:10.511: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.Java:174)
>   01-29 23:28:10.511: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.Java:179)
>   01-29 23:28:10.511: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.Java:235)
>   01-29 23:28:10.522: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.Java:259)
>   01-29 23:28:10.522: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.Java:279)
>   01-29 23:28:10.522: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.Java:121)
>   01-29 23:28:10.522: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.Java:410)
>   01-29 23:28:10.541: W/System.err(962):    at org.Apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.Java:555)

Comment: If for some reason you can't get this working, I suggest having a script server-side that does this for you, and returns a proper response.  SHOUTcast's response for 7.html should be fine... I'm not sure why you're getting these errors.  But, don't resort to scraping the data out of the stream itself when you already have it available to you, as that is quite inefficient.  If this is your server, you can also use the full XML data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out! I actually had problem with my `String url` variable.
After encoding this String with URLEncode I saw that I have %0A%0D at the of it since I got those urls from a file. (%0A%0D are chars for escape and new line, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) more about it)
Everything is working like charm now! So guys, always double check your url before you make Http request.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the variable `url`, but then you pass the original parameter to your `HttpGet`

```
 HttpGet http = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
```

So, if your `urls[0]` does not have the `http:` protocol already on it, it won't get added. I think you want the following -

```
HttpGet http = new HttpGet(url);
```

Comment: Yep, saw that, still same problem.

Comment: I am actually considering to use streamscraper http://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/ for this kind of a problem...